# Jekyll plugin works locally but not on Travis CI

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I've set up my site to build with Travis CI, and added a few plugins.

This is my `Gemfile`:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :jekyll_plugins do
    gem "github-pages"
    gem "octopress-minify-html"  # This one does not work on Travis
    gem "jekyll-git_metadata"
    gem "jekyll-paginate-v2"
    gem "jekyll-tagging"
end
```

And this is my `.travis.yml` (with irrelevant information stripped)

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler
sudo: false

#install: use default `bundle install`
script: bundle exec jekyll build
after_success: .travis/deploy.sh
```

I tried building my site locally:

```
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec jekyll build
```

And I can see the generated HTML files are minified.

But when I check pushed files from Travis CI, the HTML files are not minified. Also judging from build time, the plugin `octopress-minify-html` is not working (when it's working the build time is significantly longer).

I tried deleting my whole working directory and re-cloning from GitHub and this plugin is still working locally. I deleted Travis CI cache and let Bundler build everything again, but the plugin still doesn't work on Travis.

What went wrong on Travis?

Comment: Not using `github-pages` gem could help (use `jekyll` directly instead). It would also be better if you can just post the link to your repository..

Comment: @ashmaroli https://github.com/iBug/iBug-source (I disabled `octopress-minify-html` in Gemfile because it's not working on Travis, just remove the hash before that line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force minification with `octopress-minify-html` by setting **`minify_html: true`** in your config file.

Comment: Thanks but what's a possible reason that it didn't work on Travis?

Comment: probably an `env` issue.. Check the code here: https://github.com/octopress/minify-html/blob/c6d45d6add10f6628f9263855e53eadffcc402a2/lib/octopress-minify-html.rb#L27